# Rails 4.0 : Selected value for form_for [select]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, form-for

When submitting the below form, parameters are available in the controller with params[:teachers], but in the view (same view is rendered), selected value for "language_id" isn’t params[:teacher][:language_id], but the default one (first option).

```
<%= form_for :teacher , :url => {:action =>"search_teacher"} , :html => { :method => "post"} do | f | %>
<%= f.select :language_id , t('languages_hash'), :include_blank => false  %>
<%= f.submit  :value => t("search_button") %>
```

When debugging with the debug method in the view, « params[:teacher][:language_id] » parameter is present.

Thank you

Comment: Sorry, I don't follow.  You want the select input to return `params[:teacher][:language_id]`?

Comment: Thank you. In short, if I select the "english" language and submit the form, I want "english" selected when page is rendered (I thought it was the normal behaviour of rails forms).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By what I understood from your question, you are trying to get the previously selected language to remain selected after the form submission. For that you may need to pass a selected option in the f.select.

```
<%= f.select("Language", "language_id", Language.all.collect {|p| [ p.name, p.id ] }, { :include_blank => true, :selected => params[:language_id] }) %>
```

This may do the trick.

For more option you can go through this [link](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/select)

Comment: Thank you. I can get value with :selected => params[:teacher][:language_id] but when I access the first time, params[:teacher] doesn't exist and an error occcured.

Comment: In that case you can place a ternary operator for that. 'selected: params[:teacher][:language_id].present? ? params[:teacher][:language_id] : nil' . And if you want to make the view cleaner make it as a method. 'selected: value_for_selected' and define **value_for_selected** method over your view helper.

Comment: I think the best solution is to stop using "form_for" because teacher isn't a model object. Anyway, your answer works, thank you !

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that `t('languages_hash')` isn't returning data in the proper format that the `select` tag is expecting.

Check out [the docs](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/select_tag) - I'm guessing you'll want to wrap that in an `options_for_select` call, and possibly change the order of what is returned from `t('languages_hash')`.

Comment: I ve tried with "options_for_select", but result is same. <%= f.select :language_id , options_for_select(t('language_hash'))  %>